# Example RxJS Observable when mouse or click activity Re-starts

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm able to create 2 observables to watch mouse move and click events as such:

```
var mousemove$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
var click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
```

I'm also able to use merge() and debounceTime() to wait for either mousemove or click to not happen for 10 seconds like this:

```
var allactivity$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
    mousemove$.mapTo('Mouse!'),
    click$.mapTo('Click!')
  );

var lastact$ = allactivity$.debounceTime(10000);
```

However, I would like to somehow construct an observable for when a user Re-starts either moving the mouse or clicking after this 10 second debounceTime() limit.

Could someone help me construct this Observable?  I think I'm missing something simple.

Comment: don't quite understand the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
var restart$ = Rx.Observable.of('Kick off')
  .merge(lastact$)
  .mergeMap(() => allactivity$.skipUntil(lastact$).first());
```

### Explanation

- `Rx.Observable.of('Kick off')` - Once in the beginning, ...
- `.merge(lastact$)` - and for everytime `lastact$` emits, ...
- `.mergeMap(() => ...)` - create an observable ...
- `allactivity$` - that will observe on `allactivity$` for all items...
- `.skipUntil(lastact$)` - since the first`lastact$` emission (after the creation of this observable) ...
- `.first()` - and take only the first item (that is, the first activity happen after the `lastact$` emit)

**Edit:**

The above observable will not trigger on the first mouse move, to handle that:

```
var firstMoveAndRestart$ = restart$.merge(allactivity$.first());
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I think I'm closer.  Once I confirm it works, I'll mark this as answer.

Comment: So it almost works.  The only issue I'm running into is the first time I mouse my mouse, I get 2 restart$ events.  After that it behaves as normal.  I think it's due to the kickoff event not firing for some reason?

Comment: Oh? The `restart$` observable shouldn't have emitted when you first move your mouse. Do you want it to emit on the first move too?

Comment: I'd like it to emit as soon as it's subscribed to.  Think of it like I'm trying to record screen activity while the user is actually doing something manual. Then I want to stop recording screen activity when they haven't moved for 10 seconds.  Then I want to restart recording when they move again.