# RxJS mouse activity tracking

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm developing user activity tracking system and trying reach next goals:

1. Catch `mousemove` event once after two seconds user started moving a mouse.
2. Catch a moment after two seconds user finished moving a mouse.

I have next streams:

```
const activityStream$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

const enterActivityStream$ = activityStream$.throttleTime(1000).skip(2);

const finishActivityStream$ = activityStream$.debounceTime(2000);
```

Separately they work as intended and I would like combine them, so they will work in repeated manner.

E.g:
User started moving a mouse, after two seconds observer gets event about that (or at least `do` operator), then user finishes moving a mouse and the observer gets notified about that as well. If user started moving a mouse again, this routine repeated.

I found similar question there [Example RxJS Observable when mouse or click activity Re-starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144202/example-rxjs-observable-when-mouse-or-click-activity-re-starts) but solution seems complicated and doesn't work as intended. (`lastact$` stream fires twice, when it should fire once).

Please, can anyone give me a clue about how can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use just `merge`:

```
Observable.merge(
    enterActivityStream$, 
    activityStream$, 
    finishActivityStream$,
  )
  .subscribe(...)
```

From your description it looks like you want to start emitting any values only after the 2s interval so you could do also this:

```
enterActivityStream$
  .take(1)
  .mergeMap(() => activityStream$)
  .takeUntil(finishActivityStream$)
  .repeat()
  .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for response, Martin. Problem of both situations is `skip(2)` takes effect only first time. If I repeat this routine, `skip(2)` doesn't work anymore, so `enterActivityStream$` starts dispatch immediately (fair enough, 2 first events was skipped already). I need restart `enterActivityStream$` or the whole sequence somehow. Is something like this possible?

Comment: What is `skip(2)` supposed to do there btw when it's after `throttleTime`? It looks like you could use `.throttleTime(2000)` when in your description you mention *"Catch mousemove event once after two seconds user started moving a mouse."*

Comment: `skip(2)` supposed to skip mouse moves within first 2 seconds. Imagine if user accidentally touches mouse. I don't want track such activity. That's why I want start tracking only after two seconds of mouse moving. If I do `throttleTime(2000)` accidental touches will pass anyway. It's unwanted behavior. I'm feeling that solution must be pretty easy, but I can not figure out how to deal with it. For me it seems that i need proper filtering of mouse moves, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See my update. So there's only one emission from `enterActivityStream$` and then it keeps emitting from `activityStream$` until `.takeUntil(finishActivityStream$)`. After it completes it repeats the whole process with `repeat()`

Comment: It's seems really close. Now only the problem is that I can not get `finishActivityStream$` dispatched into `subscribe`. Can you please take a look at this [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/gukuhac/edit?js,console,output)? Can I include `finishActivityStream$` there somehow?

Comment: You can just merge it with `activityStream$.merge(finishActivityStream$)` inside `mergeMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this solution on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/catch-start-stop-mouse-activity?file=index.ts) if you are still looking for

```
import { interval, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { throttle, tap, debounceTime, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

const untilIsActiv = source.pipe(
  debounceTime(2000),
  tap(val => console.log(`caugth inactivity`))
);

const example = source
  .pipe(
    delay(2000),
    throttle(val => untilIsActiv)
  );


const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log('caugth event'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310726/martin). Finally I was able reach desired solution. It works, but I will appreciate any advise to improve this code.

```
const activityStream$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').mapTo(true);

const enterActivityStream$ = activityStream$
  .throttleTime(2000)
  .skip(1) // Skip first event to avoid accidental touches
  .takeUntil(activityStream$.debounceTime(100)) // reset after 100 milliseconds of inactivity
  .repeat(); // and then repeat

const finishActivityStream$ = activityStream$.debounceTime(2000).mapTo(false);


enterActivityStream$
  .mergeMap(() => activityStream$.merge(finishActivityStream$)) 
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .take(2) // Take true (activity started) and then false (activity stopped).
  .repeat() // And then repeat
  .subscribe(active => {
    if (active) {
      console.log('Notify about activity being started');
    } else {
      console.log('Notify about activity being stopped');
    }
  })
```